Would this Q about whether poverty causes crime be on-topic here?
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89120/crime-and-poverty-correlation-or-causation
At least one of the papers I found while looking at that was in some journal of economic history, although surely sociologists are more interested in this topic, in general.

Yes it would be on topic because it is an economics question. According to the world's leading economic association AEA, and its widely used and established JEL classification, subfields of economics include;

K42   Illegal Behavior and the Enforcement of Law
I32   Measurement and Analysis of Poverty

As far as I can see such question would not conflict with any criteria laid out in help center. However, as I understand thought cross-posting exactly same question on multiple stacks is frown upon. Other than that it could be posted here.
I do not know of any comparison of interest on this issue among sociologists and economists, but even if some question has greater interest among sociologists that does not necessarily disqualify it from being economic questions. There is great overlap between different social fields and economics is very broad. As Alfred Marshall once put it economics is the study of man in the ordinary business of life.
Even if we use less poetic and modern definition of economics from Robbins according to whom economics is "the science which studies human behaviour as a relationship between ends and scarce means which have alternative uses," it still fits. The criminal has some ends (e.g. getting more money, or increasing consumption), and scarce means that have alternative uses (e.g. time, labor, capital) that the criminal employs in some activity, for example producing something illegal, or stealing something, in order to satisfy those ends.
